# How to do grid-based (dense) optical flow on a masked image?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, opencv3.0, opticalflow

I am trying to track multiple people using a video camera. I do not want to use blob segmentation techniques.
What I want to do:

1. Perform background subtraction to obtain a mask isolating the peoples' motion.

   2. Perform grid based optical flow on those areas - 
      What would be my best bet?

I am struggling to implement. I have tried blob detection and also some optical flow based examples (sparse), sparse didn't really do it for me as I wasn't getting enough feature points from goodfeaturestotrack() - I would like to end up with at least 20 track able points per person so that's why I think a grid based method would be better for me, I will use the motion vectors obtained to classify different people ( clustering on magnitude and direction possibly? )

I am using opencv3 with Python 3.5 - but am still quite noobish in this field.
Would appreciate some guidance immensely!

Comment: It appears this was downvoted by somebody, with no explanation. I feel this is a good question although it may seem a bit broad. I can imagine what your issues may be, but perhaps you can reword it with more specifics on what you have tried and what isn't working for you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll do that

Answer (score 4):

For a sparse optical flow ( in OpenCV the pyramidal Lucas Kanade method) you don't need good features-to-track mandatory to get the positions. 
The calcOpticalFlowPyrLK function allows you to estimate the motion at predefined positions and these can be given by you too. 
So just initialized a grid of cv::Point2f by your self, e.g. create a list of points and set the positions to the grid points located at your blobs, and run calcOpticalFlowPyrLK().

The idea of the good features-to-track method is that it gives you the points where the calcOpticalFlowPyrLK() result is **more likely** to be accurate and this is on image locations with edge-like structures. But in my experiences this gives not always the optimal feature point set. I prefer to use regular grids as feature point sets.